# How to get prestashop product attributes through SQL

Tags: mysql, sql, database, relational-database, prestashop

I need to build a report for a prestashop site showing product id, name, and stock. So far I've done just that through the following query:

```
SELECT product.id_product, product_lang.name, stock_available.quantity
FROM ps_product product, ps_product_lang product_lang, ps_stock_available stock_available
WHERE stock_available.id_product = product.id_product
AND stock_available.id_product = product.id_product
AND product_lang.id_lang =1
AND product.reference =  ''
AND product_lang.id_product = product.id_product
```

which outputs something like:

```
|===============================|
|   id   |   name   |   stock   |
|   1    | earring  |    45     |
|===============================|
```

The problem is that some products have the same name and same ID but different attributes, so i'm getting stuff like this:

```
|===============================|
|   id   |   name   |   stock   |
|   1    | earring  |    45     |
|   1    | earring  |    76     |
|   1    | earring  |    9      |
|===============================|
```

What i need is to add a new field showing the attributes that differentiate them, so the final output would be something like this:

```
|================================================|
|   id   |   name   |   attributes   |   stock   |
|   1    | earring  | yellow, short  |    45     |
|   1    | earring  | red, short     |    76     |
|   1    | earring  | red, long      |    9      |
|================================================|
```

But I can't figure out how the attributes tables (because there are several of them) relate to the products table in order to add the proper statements to the query and get the desired behaviour.

If there are any prestashop database experts around, or anyone that could help, I would really appreciate it.

Answer (score 0):

Try this:

```
SELECT DISTINCT
    p.id_product, pl.name, psa.quantity
FROM ps_product p 
    LEFT JOIN ps_product_lang pl ON (pl.id_product = p.id_product)   
    LEFT JOIN ps_stock_available psa ON (p.id_product = psa.id_product)
GROUP by p.id_product
```